# Visual Studio2012 Output text

Tags: c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012, output

I wrote the following code in visual studio 2012:

```
using System;
class Example
{
    static void main()
    {
        int x = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("X Contains:" + x);
        int y = x / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("y contains");
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.WriteLine("A Sample C# Program");
    }
}
```

There were no errors, but the output window was empty. It did not print anything. What should I do so that I get the text displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console prints to the console (add Console.ReadLine() at the end so it doesn't terminate immediately).
To print to output use Trace.WriteLine() or Debug.WriteLine()

Answer (score 1):

Your are writing to dos-console and expecting VS Output window to show written things.
With your current code You shoud run that in Console Application project. it would open the Dos-command console an executes your commands on it.

Event if you are in console application project, you will see console flashes and then disappears.

Add `Console.ReadLine();` after `Console.WriteLine("A Sample C# Program");`. this holds the console open.

Answer (score 0):

This code is work good try it.
You Should play by click(ctrl+F5)
IF you play With "F5" it will terminate immediately.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1{

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        int x = 100;
        Console.WriteLine("X Contains:" + x);
        int y = x / 2;
        Console.WriteLine("y contains");
        Console.WriteLine(y);
        Console.WriteLine("A Sample C# Program");


    }
}
```

}